# Entity Framework and repository pattern problem

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using generic repository pattern with methods:

```
    private ObjectQuery<T> ObjectQueryList()
    {
        var list = CamelTrapEntities.CreateQuery<T>(EntitySetName);
        return list;
    }
```

```
    public IQueryable<T> List()
    {
        return ObjectQueryList();
    }
```

Metod List() returns IQueryable<T>, becase IQueryable<T> is easy to mock. I also have extension method:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> obj, string path)
    {
        if (obj is ObjectQuery<T>)
            (obj as ObjectQuery<T>).Include(path);

        return obj;
    }
```

This method is used outside of repository to get entity list with navigation properties already loaded, for example: List.Include("CreatedBy"). The problem is that it doesn't work. All includes are ignored. when I change List() method to

```
    public ObjectQuery<T> List()
    {
        return ObjectQueryList();
    }
```

everything works fine.

How should I implement repository pattern to be able to execute more complex queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reflector gave me an answer:

```
public ObjectQuery<T> Include(string path)
{
    EntityUtil.CheckStringArgument(path, "path");
    return new ObjectQuery<T>(base.QueryState.Include<T>((ObjectQuery<T>) this, path));
}
```

Include returns new ObjectQuery object and my Include function returned old object. Changing to

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> obj, string path)
{
    if (obj is ObjectQuery<T>)
        return (obj as ObjectQuery<T>).Include(path);

    return obj;
}
```

solved the problem. Few hours lost and I hate Entity Framework more:)

It made me also realise that I should create another List function with Include parameter and not allow doing includes outside repository.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx) is the most comprehensive Repository pattern implementation I've seen for EF.  I can't say for sure if it will allow you to do Include(), but if I read the implementation right it should.

Answer (score 1):

With EntityFramework 4.1, DbExtensions (`System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions`) resolves this problem, and natively adds both `.Include([string path])` and `.Include([property expression])` for any `IQueryable<T>`.

Just be sure that the project using your repository references EntityFramework, and, as with any extension methods, specify `using System.Data.Entity;` in your class file to gain access to these extensions.